# Sprite.OverridePhysicsShape( ? );

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the link that says about: 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.OverridePhysicsShape.html

The part of `IList` I understand. But `Vector2[]`, I do not understand how I would use it to populate with data and use it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't actually used this and I'm not in a position to knock up a quick test at the moment, but this might help. You should be able to define the physics boundaries for your sprite as a collection of shapes.

Imagine you have a single sprite with two separate components and a gap in the middle. Rather than defining a single physics shape around the entire thing, you might choose to define the physics shape in two parts so that it better conforms to the two parts of the image.

Therefore, the IList is your collection of shapes. This could quite likely just contain a single shape. The Vector2 array defines the points (at least three points in sprite space) for that individual shape. All of the Vector2 arrays combined form the overall physics shape.

EDIT: How to set the values? Something like this perhaps?

```
void Start ()
{
    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    Sprite sprite = spriteRenderer.sprite;

    sprite.OverridePhysicsShape(new List<Vector2[]> {
        new Vector2[] { new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 1) },
        new Vector2[] { new Vector2(2, 2), new Vector2(3, 2), new Vector2(3, 3), new Vector2(2, 3) },
    });
}
```

*DISCLAIMER: Not sure if that actually works.*

Comment: Thank you. But my question is how to: insert into my vector2 [] the physical forms of the sprie. That is my doubt ...
How do I store fitness? What are these data?
Forgive me, in that part I lose myself ...

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.
But when you save in a List <Vector2 []> the existing vertices in your sprite and use them in that function would it be correct? Example:
  GetComponent <PolygonCollider2D> (). Points = GetComponent <SpriteRenderer> (). Sprite.vertices;

The results were even better than I expected, but they are not correct.
Example with image: https://imgur.com/a/yW8Apur

I am very grateful for your help. Thank you.
One tip I want from you, as you saw in this image, is a hole made with transparency but I want the collider to ignore it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but the official Unity answer is "Don't bother." Calls to Sprite.OverridePhysicsShape() **only work when importing (or reimporting) images** and cannot work at runtime (or even in the editor). Please see this link about it:

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/sprite-dot-overridephysicsshape-raises-an-error-when-using-it-in-editor-mode

The previous answer is correct that this is a list of Vector2[] arrays, but the coordinates of the Vector2 points must all be between [0,0] and [1,1] because the coordinates are parametric to the bounds of the Sprite.

Here is some code that should work. It doesn't throw an error now (in v2020.3.1), but it also doesn't seem to do anything.

```
public class SpritePhysicsShapeTest : MonoBehaviour {
    public Sprite sprite;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {
        List<Vector2[]> pts = new List<Vector2[]>();
        pts.Add( new Vector2[] { 
            new Vector2( 0, 0 ),
            new Vector2( 0.5f, 0 ),
            new Vector2( 0.5f, 0.5f ),
            new Vector2( 0, 0.5f ) 
        } );
        sprite.OverridePhysicsShape(pts);
    }
}
```

If you're trying to programmatically affect collision on a Unity Tilemap, my current solution is to have one Tilemap for visuals (with 256 possible Sprites) and a second invisible Tilemap that handles collisions (with only 16 possible Sprites). This seems to work well, though I did have to manually draw those 16 Sprites' collisions in the Sprite Editor.